# Error message when opening an application in WSL

Tags: linux, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, qstandardpaths

I'm getting this error message when opening an application in Windows Subsystem for Linux from the terminal:

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-adduser'
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Could not connect to any X display.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What application are you trying to run? There will be no desktop with WSL as the environment runs pretty much like a container.

Comment: I'm trying to run Wireshark

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark will need to GUI to run in WSL and so you will be better off using the terminal version of wireshark which is tshark

https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html

Install by running bash as administrator at Windows level and then executing the command:

```
sudo apt-get install tshark
```